# Why am I getting HDD total space less than 931 GiB?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, size

I've been trying for a few days already, but still cannot figure it out how to get the proper size of my HDD drive with a python script.
My HDD is 1Tb. As I know in Gb it is 1000Gb, and in GiB it is 931GiB roughly.
When I type in the terminal `lsblk` it shows this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   931G  0 part /
```

Ok.Then I try `lshw --class disk` it shows 931GiB as well:

```
*-disk                    
       description: ATA Disk
       product: ST1000LM035-1RK1
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sda
       version: SDM2
       serial: WDEWEKZF
       size: 931GiB (1TB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=f166251c-436c-421f-aba8-9910d76f9fab logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

Then I try to get the size through a python script:

```py
total, used, free, percent = disk_usage('/')

print(f"Total: {total}")
print(f"Used: {used}")
print(f"Free: {free}")

total2, used2, free2, percent2 = disk_usage('/boot/efi')

print(f"Total: {total2}")
print(f"Used: {used2}")
print(f"Free: {free2}")
```

output:

```
Total: 982900588544
Used: 118413897728
Free: 814486605824

Total: 535805952
Used: 5484544
Free: 530321408
```

982900588544 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 = 915 GiB.

535805952 = 500 MiB.

`df` command shows this:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8092080         0   8092080   0% /dev
tmpfs            1627768      1712   1626056   1% /run
/dev/sda2      959863856 115646148 795389500  13% /
tmpfs            8138832     12368   8126464   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            8138832         0   8138832   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         523248      5356    517892   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs            1627764        24   1627740   1% /run/user/1000
```

The sum of all 1K-blocks gives 1Tb.

So, where is another 931 - 915 = 16 GiB of HDD space?
And how to get the size in a correct way?
Linux Mint 20.1 x64

Thanks.

Comment: `blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda` <-- this is the real block size of your first hard disk. In bytes. There is no cheat, no trickery, counting 1GB sometimes to 2^30 and sometimes to 10^9 trickery, nothing. Just the byte size.

Comment: The sum of all 1K-blocks is an incorrect calculation. Only / and /boot/efi are actually from your hard drive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If that's ext4, it's the size that is lost to filesystem metadata, mainly inode tables. As an example, a /home partition here.

- Partition is 751619276800 bytes (`sudo /sbin/blockdev --getsize64 /dev/mapper/Watt-home`)
- "df" size is 739691814912 (`df --block-size=1 /home`)
- Inode count is 45875200 (`df -i /home`)
- Inodes on ext4 are 256 bytes.

So if you do the math, (751619276800-739691814912-(45875200*256))/1024^2 ≈ 175MiB. That's the rest of the filesystem metadata (superblocks, etc.).

To make sure this is right, compare to a filesystem that was initialized with a lower inode ratio — one way is with the `-T largefile` or `-T largefile4` option (see `/etc/mke2fs.conf` for the possibilities). I have one here:

- Partition size: 429496729600
- df size: 429229522944
- inodes: 409600

Note how much closer the df size is to the partition size (over 99.9%). That's because there are far fewer inodes. And if you do that math again, (429496729600-429229522944-(409600*256))/1024^2 ≈ 155MiB.

Keep in mind that on ext4, the number of inodes is a hard limit on the number of files you can have. It (or rather the ratio of 1 inode per N blocks) is also set once at mkfs and can not be changed. But if you have a filesystem that you know will only be used to store large files, you can save some space by having fewer of inodes, as I did on my second filesystem.

You can see the overhead subtracted out in the kernel source code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/super.c#L6095 — and also the existence of a `minixdf` mount option that will stop it from doing so, and maybe do more weirdness too. I didn't check, and the only documentation I found about it was them trying to remove it but keeping it when people complained.

BTW: In addition to this overhead for inode tables, etc., there is often 5% of space reserved, typically for root. That doesn't subtract from the total size, but will subtract from the available space. You can change this amount `tune2fs -m`; other options let you specify by block count instead (`-r`) and change which user (`-u`) or group (`-g`) can use the reserved space. One benefit is even if users fill a partition, the sysadmin has some space to use for recovery.

Note: ext2/ext3 used 128-byte inodes, half the size. Small filesystems still do. You can actually set it a mkfs time with the `-I` option; see the mkfs.ext4 manpage for caveats (I would not recommend changing to 128).

Comment: also the defaults and the types settable with `-T` should be in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`, with the default being one inode of 256 bytes per for each 16k of filesystem size, so 1.56 % overhead. Pretty close to the 1.72 % overhead they're seeing, the rest presumably being other filesystem structures.

Comment: I would add that by default `mkfs.extN` reserves 5% of the blocks to the superuser. This can be changed when calling those programs or tweaked postfactum using `tune2fs`. (I'd also recommend the OP to play with `dumpe2fs`. Both programs are available in the `e2fsprogs` package on Debian and derivatives.)

Comment: Essentially "how much data can this disk fit?" and "how much data can this filesystem fit?" are different questions, even when you fill a disk with one filesystem.

Comment: @ilkkachu mentioned the config file in the latest edit

Comment: @kostix Added a paragraph ("BTW: …", 2nd to last) to explain that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is lost to hidden internal data used by the file system itself to bookkeep all the file structure. It is not displayed by tools you are using, and thus appears as missing.